# How to play a video from WinForms resources in a axWindowsMediaPlayer?

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

Does anybody know or have any idea for how to play a video from the applications resources into an axWindowsMediaPlayer component?

I mean something like:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.TheProperty = Resources.MyVideoResource;
```

Would be very nice, but I don't think such property exists..

Comment: Sure, WMP is a media player.  Designed to deal with media coming from somewhere else.  You'll have to step lower to stream from a resource.  Like the DirectShow api, put .net behind it to find C# code.

Comment: To help you, you can visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094176/c-sharp-load-video-from-resources-folder-not-playing/36673786#36673786

Answer (score 3):

Add Interop.axWMPLib and / or Interop.WMPLib references to your project

(if i don't remember wrong axWmpLib works with windows mp and if no wmp found on the pc then wmplib connects with any installed -or default- media player automatically which supports wmplib -i.e. winamp or splayer- .. i only worked once with this last year -2011 august- to surprise to my g.f. for her b-day.. so its worked as well before with a media list contains 2 mp3s and i give these codes directly except paths)

```
        private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_ClickEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_ClickEvent e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = fullPathOfYourFirstMedia;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play(); // activates the play button
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.next(); // activates the next button
            WMPLib.IWMPMedia media = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(fullPathOfYourSecondMedia);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.appendItem(media);
        }
```

if you take the medias from the resources then simply add your medias to your project's recources and give the full path strings' start as "`Application.Startup`"