# C# load video from resources folder not playing

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I trying to load my video from the resources folder but its not playing automatically once my form load. Can I know what mistake i have done. Thank you.

This is my c# code:

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"Resources/abc.mp4";

        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I have solved it my ownself. Actually, I accidentally added the **@** symbol into my url. That causes the problem. This is the updated code.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "Resources\\abc.mp4";

    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that king of thing, you must get the stream of your resource. 
So that code should work for you because works for me :)

```
// temporary file path - your temp file = video.avi
 var strTempFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Video.avi");

        try
        {
            // ResourceName = the resource you want to play
            File.WriteAllBytes(strTempFile, Properties.Resources.ResourceName);
            axWMP.URL = strTempFile;
            axWMP.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            // Manage me
        }
```

You can implement a axWMP_PlayStateChange method to remove video.Avi at the end.

Hope it could help you